# Healthkit data: Is the XML data you manually export from the iPhone the same as the Healthkit data

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-watch, health-kit

I want to know if the environmental noise data from Apple watch (or for that matter any health data parameter) has a higher resolution if you access it via Healthkit (or from iCloud) vs. manually export xml file. The noise level data I exported from the phone is in 30 sec increments and want to know if the watch is collecting the data at a higher sample rate, e.g., 1 Hz

Thanks